# How to download data from web server Mysql database to Arduino Yun using PHP?

Tags: php, arduino, arduino-yun

I am using an Arduino Yun for my project. I need to download data from web host, 000webhost, mysql database to my Arduino Yun. How can I achieve that? I want to use php file, which should be working independently. How should I on the Arduino Yun side.
Here is my PHP script code:

```
<?php
    $db_name = "00000";
    $mysql_user = "0000";
    $mysql_pass = "0000";
    $server_name = "mysql9.000webhost.com";

    $con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$db_name);

    $dname = $_GET["dname"];
    $dlastname = $_GET["dlastname"];
    $pname = $_GET["pname"];
    $plastname = $_GET["plastname"];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM drug WHERE dname = ? AND dlastname = ? AND pname = ? AND plastname = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssss", $dname, $dlastname, $pname, $plastname);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $dname, $dlastname, $pname, $plastname, $drug, $time, $minute, $amount, $op);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = false;  

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["userID"] = $userID;  
        $response["dname"] = $dname;
        $response["dlastname"] = $dlastname;
        $response["pname"] = $pname;
        $response["plastname"] = $plastname;
        $response["drug"] = $drug;
        $response["time"] = $time;
        $response["minute"] = $minute;
        $response["amount"] = $amount;
        $response["op"] = $op;
    }
    //echo"Drug: ".$drug;
    //echo"Hour: ".$time;
    //echo"Minute: ".$minute;
    //echo"Op: ".$op;


?>
```

Basically just get the input from Arduino: dname, dlastname, pname, and plastname. And then search the whole table. If these four columns match, just download the whole information of that row from Mysql database.

Two question:
1. If there is no problem with php script, how should write the code in Arduino yun 
2.How to download data from php file? Is there something like a return so that I can get all data in Arduino Yun?